# Tensorflow applying operations inside a model: FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say I have CNN model that outputs N probability maps as mask the same size of the input image in a Unet like fashion. I would then want to apply for example least square fit on top of each mask to get coefficients for functions as output instead and use these to calculate my models loss.

```
def unet_model(...)
    # init unet model
    ...
    ...
    # final layer
    mask_out = layers.Conv2D(output_channels, (1,1), activation='softmax')(conv9)

    # start applying e.g least squares fit here
    eq_list = tf.Variable((x_map, y_map, mask_out))
    transp = tf.transpose(a)
    ...
```

transp would get the following error when I initialize the model. I have tested the least squares fit operations elsewhere.

```
FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar1423 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar1423/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist. name: transpose/
```

I have some assumptions such as that transpose cannot deal with placeholders axis for batch sizes, but am generally clueless about this.

Answer (score 0):

before adding each variables I needed to make sure that x_map and y_map also is batched by expanding the dims with axis -1

Comment: hmm this seems to be incorrect, I fixed the code to now accept batches correctly, but it now seems that tf.Variable is not initialized